# Make image into a box

Tags: html, css

I have a border of 100px / 100px with the name of companies next to it. 
Have to fit the company logo in this box. The logos are available in different sizes.

I have the following code.

```
.logo-border {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
.company-logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML CoDe

```
<div class="logo-border">
   <img class="company-logo" src="/images/abc.png">
</div>
```

This makes the image appear at the top of the box.

If I add `object-fit: contain;` in the company-logo class it works fine. But "object-fit" does not work in Internet explorer.

Have tried using position. But that didnot work either.
Kindly help me !

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.logo-border {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  display:table;
  text-align:center;
}
.company-logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This will center align vertically and horizontally as with table property you can use `vertical-align:middle` to vertically align it and `text-align:center` is for horizontal align

Answer (score 0):

See this code

I have added **display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle; text-align:center**

And its working fine now.

```css
.logo-border {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
.company-logo {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-border">
   <img class="company-logo" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wECsXJqZ_I0/VDmPRlNa_MI/AAAAAAAAIfQ/UbS33drV1qo/s1600/car%2Blogo%2Bpicture%2B3.png">
</div>
```

Comment: can you tell me the reason why you down my votes. My code is perfectly fine. give me reason I will appreciate.

Comment: it is because of  meta effect of [this Question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319870/what-to-do-when-particular-user-is-sharing-his-own-sites-link-in-every-answer) asked on META STACKOVERFLOW.